# How to upload a signed .aab bundle in visual studio 2019 to play store

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, publish

This is my first app to publish and I have tried for over a week now with no success. I have tried two ways to publish an app on the play store.

1. Through "register Google API access" but I received an error message **error 400: invalid_request** indicating that the OAuth 2.0 rule for security is not respected
2. I also tried to upload an .aab bundle from Google console in "testing". I received another error message that **the bundle is not signed**

I have tried many other posts with no success. Can someone help? Am really desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already been able to publish the app, but I will post here in case anyone find this helpful.

1. For the first error (error 400: invalid_request) you need to go to APIs & Services -> OAuth consent screen, Edit app and in the second step called Permissions you will need to add the APIs that your app uses. Finally, in the third step (Test users) you will need to add yourself (by your e-mail address). Then, you will need to retry the integration between Visual Studio and the Play Store.
2. In order to sign the app you need to follow the steps shown in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows). I think you have already completed some steps shown there, but check if you missed something. Then, having the integration between Visual Studio and the Play Store completed successfully, you will be able to select the Test (or Internal, Alpha, Beta) Google Play Track to publish your app. The other alternative is doing it by manual upload. In order to do so, you have to go to the Archive Manager (right click on your Android project, Archive option), press the Distribute button and select Ad Hoc channel. The file produced there will be signed by you. It can be directly uploaded to the Play Store.